# How to import a text file and prep for plotting and analysis with Python

Tags: python, matlab

This is my first attempt of migrating from Matlab to Python 3.4 using Mac OS Yosemite.  I'm stuck with what is probably a very simple issue, and here it is:

Inside a folder, I have multiple files with different headers and data. All of them have a structure as shown in below's example. I would like to perform these operations:

- remove all the lines that start with '#', such as to leave only table of numbers in a column format
- take the N-th column of a and plot it as the y-axis vs. the M-th column.
- take the N-th column of a *certain* file, and plot it as the y-axis vs. the M-th column of *another* file.
- take the N-th column of several files, and plot it as the y-axis vs. the M-th column of one of them

I know the question is rather general, but this is so simple in Matlab using the "import" command (which is reads what is header and what is data), that I imagine it should be simple in python. I can't even show you what I've tried, since my attempt was so unsuccessful.  I would really appreciate anyone's help.

Here is the file structure:

```
#S 3  
#D 
#T 1  
#Q 0 0 24.0056
#P0 96.3973 53.9652 2.846164 0 10.159824 -0.1745831 -12.699097 70.863561
#P1 0.72284528 -0.62815186 -1.9 78.79958 7.8 61.3002 1.2075 -1.000035
#P2 3.3 10 9.46 0 0 2.1 -1.11 -1.605
#P3 0.25 -0.3 -0.22 -1.13 -0.05 -0.65 -0.28 -2.5
#P4 0.575 -1.475 3.404 3.204 2.86 1.86 -0.355 -0.655
#P5 6.45 5.95 1.99998 0.500066 1.99998 -0.299943 0.75 -0.29
#P6 0.76 -0.31 -0.115 -0.4 -0.341875 
#UE 11.2115 1.10587 11.9701 11.2748 
#N 19
#L Chi  H  K  L  DegK  Reg_DegK  Field  Current  Epoch  Seconds  Iaps  IonCh2  
2.5461672 -0.0009333 -0.0588542 24.0053 4.957 4.7046 -0.0006 0.0004 1244.977 1 101.7462 152960 2504 195506 187083 39896 272 30537 814
2.5661659 -0.000871762 -0.0549309 24.0053 4.9566 4.7046 0 -0.0002 1248.741 1 101.7148 152505 2484 195454 187013 39586 273 30299 805
2.5861645 -0.000810128 -0.0510075 24.0054 4.9568 4.7045 -0.0007 -0.0022 1252.477 1 101.7028 152727 2478 195607 187172 39711 273 30391 809
2.6061631 -0.000748396 -0.0470841 24.0054 4.9569 4.7047 0.0022 0.002 1256.208 1 102.202 152328 2478 195446 187022 39438 272 30182 799
2.6261617 -0.000686567 -0.0431607 24.0054 4.9569 4.7045 0.0009 0.0004 1259.944 1 102.201 152605 2495 195405 186963 39760 272 30422 874
2.6461604 -0.000624641 -0.0392373 24.0055 4.9566 4.7051 0.0004 -0.001 1263.685 1 102.198 152577 2491 195396 186994 39675 272 30356 900
2.666159 -0.000562619 -0.0353139 24.0055 4.9576 4.7054 0 -0.0002 1267.430 1 102.1768 152554 2483 195651 187219 39622 272 30325 826
2.6861576 -0.000500499 -0.0313905 24.0055 4.9569 4.7045 0.0017 -0.001 1271.155 1 102.1342 152685 2490 195365 186945 39775 272 30443 833
#R 11 4.9547 (scan nr., Y_PEAK, at pos., FWHM, at pos., COM, SUM, Time, TEMP_CS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, if you to get the lines that do not start with #, this snippet of code will get you by.

```
with open("somefile.txt", "r") as indata: # opens and reads file 
  for line in indata.readlines(): # splits file into lines
    if not line.startswith("#"): # if the line doesn't start with # print it
      print line
```

Since we used a with statement to open and read the file we do not have to explicitly close the file.  The with statement will handle that.
Next, if I wanted to create a new file that have those lines removed I would do something like this. Note that first with statement will open a file for writing with the name I passed to it.  This is great for one file, but not if you have to iterate over many files.

```
with open('someoutfile', 'w') as outdata:
  with open("somefile.txt", "r") as indata:
    for line in indata.readlines():
      if not line.startswith("#"):
        outdata.write(line)
```

Lastly, here is the snippet that will iterate over the folders contents and create new files with the formatting you require

```
import os

def get_file_names(folder):
    """Yields a one file at a time from the outfiles folder"""
    for i in os.listdir(folder):   #pass the name of the directory or path to the directory          
      yield i

folder_files_live_in = "somedirectory"
for filename in get_file_names(folder_files_live_in):
  outfile = "outfile"
  count = 1 # gives the output files some level of uniqueness 
  with open(outfile + str(count) , 'w') as outdata:
    with open(folder_files_live_in + '/' + filename, "r") as indata: #the somedirectory is the same directory you passed in the get_file_names() function
      for line in indata.readlines():
        if not line.startswith("#"):
          outdata.write(line)
  count += 1
```